# WPF Binding Style.Trigger To Parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, watermark

I'm trying to implement a Watermark solution for my ComboBoxes I found somewhere on the web (I can't find the page again) but have problems with the binding. The original solution had static text which I would like to replace using a binding to the ComboBoxes Tag property.

This is what I have so far:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="Watermark" TileMode="None" Opacity="0.4" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=Tag}"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Watermark}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Tag="Categories"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}" Tag="SubCategories"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Whatever}" Tag="Whatever"/>
```

Unfortunately it looks like the "FindAncestor" part is not working.
Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not that easy.

First, you cannot set the `ComboxBox` `Background` property like this. It becomes obvious, as soon as you try to replace the RelativeSource-Binding by some hardcoded text.

Second, you have to make sure that the VisualBrush ressource is part of the VisualTree of your `ComboBox`, not somewhere else (in the containing `Grid`, for example).

Both problems could be solved by retemplating the `ComboBox`. This can be done in Blend or Visual Studio by first creating a new template (as copy). Then you need to change it a bit.

There will be a `Grid` named "templateRoot". Add your watermark ressource:

```
<Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="Watermark" TileMode="None" Opacity="0.4" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=Tag}"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>...
```

Then, at the end of the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` part you need to insert another `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource Watermark}"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

It must be a `MultiTrigger` condition, because otherwise it's not bindable.

Comment: I don't understand your first point because If I replace the RelativeSource-Binding by some hardcoded text it does work...?

Comment: For me it doesn't. If it matters you should post a complete sample for demonstration.

Comment: lol now this is funny. I've created a sample project which didn't show the watermark. After I added the MahApps.Metro nuget package and adjusted the styles in the App.xaml it works. They must be implementing this behavior somehow. Unfortunately I'm still unable to map the Binding to the Tag property of the ComboBoxes. Anyway you can find the solution here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb219vbqdo2co45/WpfApplication1.7z?dl=1

Comment: I don't see where you tried the ControlTemplate I described.